# SurfaceView clears it's contents when detaching

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview

I'm using SurfaceView inside Fragment. When I replace fragment with another one, SurfaceView blinks black for a second and then SurfaceView's fragment is detached.

One popular suggestion is to use `setZOrderOnTop(true)`. But when I use it, SurfaceView simply has the same color as background and doesn't blink. But then it shows over other UI elements and creates more problems.

I noticed that in both cases SurfaceView clears its contents before destroying, so `setZOrderOnTop` doesn't matter.

Can anybody explain why SurfaceView clears its content when detaching? But another UI elements (Buttons, Lists) don't have such behaviour.

**EDIT**
SurfaceView clears when method `onWindowVisibilityChanged` of SurfaceView class is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround - first add new fragment, then show it and hide old. And then remove old in the async task. The solution is a bit confusing, but I didn't find anything better.
In the following example old fragment has tag `fragment` and the new one `fragment2`.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "fragment2").commit();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragment).commit();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment")).commit();
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment")).commit();                      
                    }
                }, 1000);
```

In such method SurfaceView blinks black also, but it is not visible at that moment.